# mariaDB problem. Trying to create a table with Constraint that has multiple-choice input

Tags: mysql, mariadb, constraints, multiple-choice

i have the following code i try to execute

```
CREATE TABLE ShoppingCentreShop (
CentreCode varchar(255),
ShopNo int,
Category  varchar(255),
CustomerRating int,
**CONSTRAINT CHK_Category CHECK ( Category in ('FASHION', 'ENTERTAINMENT','FOOD')),**
CONSTRAINT CHK_CustomerRating CHECK ( CustomerRating between 1 and 5),
CONSTRAINT fk_ShoppingCentre_CentreCode FOREIGN KEY (CentreCode)  REFERENCES ShoppingCentre(CentreCode),
CONSTRAINT fk_Shop_ShopNo FOREIGN KEY (ShopNo)  REFERENCES Shop(ShopNo)
);
```

and i get the following error codes

1. “A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes. (near "CHECK" at position 147)
2. Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Category" at position 155)
3. Unrecognized statement type. (near "in" at position 164)

the error appears on the bold line of code
"
I am a beginner in MySQL so any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: i also get the following error line
"#1005 - Can't create table `shopping_centres`.`shoppingcentreshop` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)"

Comment: When you remove the now highlighted line, do you still get errors, and, if so, what are they?

Comment: Are you sure these error messages come from mariadb in the first place?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hMVPPCNqWbLCfUnATUgQoB/0

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when i remove the problematic line i get an error code on the following line which is also a multiple choice constraint

Comment: @shadow i cant really answer that as i dont know how to..

Comment: @P.Salmon the thing is i configured it with this code a few days ago and there was no issue but i've tried to reproduce it today and i get the aforementioned error codes

Comment: All I can suggest is you have some non printing characters in the code. Try copying and pasting from fiddle

Comment: what version of MySQL or MariaDB are you using?

Comment: I tried on MariaDB 10.1 to 10.4, and MySQL 5.7 and 8.0, but I don't get any errors on any of these ...

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe i am using mariadb version 10.4.11

Comment: Even when explicitly testing with 10.4.11 I can't reproduce this (I removed the FK constraints, but the two CHECK constraints are parsed without error)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ENUM()?

```
CREATE TABLE ShoppingCentreShop
(
  CentreCode varchar(255),
  ShopNo int,
  Category ENUM('FASHION','ENTERTAINMENT','FOOD'),
  CustomerRating int,
  CONSTRAINT CHK_CustomerRating CHECK (CustomerRating BETWEEN 1 AND 5),
  CONSTRAINT fk_ShoppingCentre_CentreCode FOREIGN KEY (CentreCode) REFERENCES ShoppingCentre(CentreCode),
  CONSTRAINT fk_Shop_ShopNo FOREIGN KEY (ShopNo) REFERENCES Shop(ShopNo)
)
```

Comment: i tried the enum and i get the following error code   "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CustomerRating between 1 and 5),
CONSTRAINT fk_ShoppingCentre_CentreCode FOREIG' at line 7"

Comment: In title you said that you work with MySQL not MariaDB. Also you must have MySQL  8.0.16 and above for full CHECK functionality. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: "Also you must have MySQL 8.0.16 and above for full CHECK functionalit ..."

OR MariaDB >= 10.2 which already had them working about two years earlier ... just say'in

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe i have mariadb version 10.4.11 as i mentioned above

Comment: Instead of CHECK constraint try using ENUM(1,2,3,4,5) type for your CustomerRating column instead of int type.